# jQuery remote validator server generated error messages are not being displayed

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validator to validate a form.  My server returns `true` if an email is not being used, and something like `this email is already being used` if it is being used.  Using Firebug, I see the responses to jQuery validator's GET requests as either being `true` or `this email is already being used`, and I believe the server is working appropriately.

When the server returns these errors, however, they are not being displayed as errors.  Other non-remote errors like an invalid email, however, are being displayed.  While the remote errors are not being displayed, they are in fact preventing the form from being submitted.

As shown below, I am also using custom client-side messages, but I have removed them thinking they might be responsible, but get the same outcome.

EDIT.  My server is returning `'true'` for no error, and `'some error message'` for an error.  If my server returns `'false'`, however, the client side message is displayed.

How do I have jQuery validator display server generated error messages?

```
{
    "ignore": [],
    "rules": {
        "email": {
            "email": true,
            "maxlength": 45,
            "invite":true,
            "remote": "openContactEmail"
        }
    },
    "messages": {
        "email": {
            "email":"Please enter a valid email address.",
            "remote":"Another contact is using this email for this account."
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "email": {
            "id": 123
        }
    },
    "remote": "path_to_validation_file.php"
}
```

Comment: Showing your server-side code is critical for anyone other than yourself to be able to solve this one.  Otherwise, we would just be guessing that you failed to echo the response as JSON.

Comment: @Sparky  Yes, I agree, and felt bad for not doing so.  Just was totally convinced it wasn't, but obviously was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure remote like this returning a json having isError and message.

Then configure dataFilter function to return message.

```
 remote: {
        url: "path_to_validation_file.php"
},
        dataFilter: function(data) {
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            if(json.isError == "true") {
                return "\"" + json.errorMessage + "\"";
            } else {
                return '';
            }

        }
    }
```

They are also recommending [this](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)

Answer (score 0):

My server had been returning:

```
echo($error?'true':$message);
```

I changed it to the following, and now server generated messages are being displayed.

```
echo($error?json_encode(true):json_encode($message));
```

Per http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/:

> The serverside response must be a JSON string that must be "true" for
>   valid elements, and can be "false", undefined, or null for invalid
>   elements, using the default error message. I

Comment: Yes, that seems to be smart one then my answer :)

Comment: @AnilKumar  Yea, seems to be.  In my original question, however, I stated that the server response was working correct, and that turned out not to be the case.